# Mysql query takes a lot of time to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an timesheet application, and writing a PHP code to fetch all the timesheets till date. This is the query that I have written to fetch the timesheets -

`SELECT a.accnt_name, u.username, DATE_FORMAT(t.in_time, '%H:%i') inTime, DATE_FORMAT(t.out_time, '%H:%i') outTime, DATE_FORMAT(t.work_time, '%H:%i') workTime, w.wrktyp_name, t.remarks, DATE_FORMAT(t.tmsht_date, '%d-%b-%Y') tmshtDate, wl.loctn_name, s.serv_name, t.status_code, t.conv_kms convkms, t.conv_amount convamount FROM timesheets t, accounts a, services s, worktypes w, work_location wl, users WHERE a.accnt_code=t.accnt_code and w.wrktyp_code=t.wrktyp_code and wl.loctn_code=t.loctn_code and s.serv_code=t.serv_code and t.usr_code = u. ORDER BY tmsht_date desc`

The where clause contains the clauses to get the actual values of respective codes from respective tables.

The issue is that this query is taking a lot of time to execute and the application crashes at the end of few minutes.

I ran this query in the phpmyadmin, there it works without any issues.

Need help in understanding what might be the cause behind the slowness in the execution.

Comment: Can use indexing for select fields for faster execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use EXPLAIN to see the execution plan for the query. Make sure MySQL has suitable indexes available, and is using those indexes.

The query text seems to be missing the name of a column here...

```
  t.usr_code = u.    ORDER
                 ^^^
```

We can "guess" that's supposed to be `u.usr_code`, but that's just a guess.

How many rows are supposed to be returned? How large is the resultset?

Is your client attempting to "store" all of the rows in memory, and crashing because it runs out of memory?

If so, I recommend you avoid doing that, and fetch the rows as you need them.

Or, consider adding some additional predicates in the WHERE clause to return just the rows you need, rather than all the rows in the table.

It's 2015. Time to ditch the old-school comma syntax for join operation, and use `JOIN` keyword instead, and move join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause. And format it.  The database doesn't care, but it will make it easier on the poor soul that needs to decipher your SQL statement.

```
  SELECT a.accnt_name
       , u.username
       , DATE_FORMAT(t.in_time  ,'%H:%i') AS inTime
       , DATE_FORMAT(t.out_time ,'%H:%i') AS outTime
       , DATE_FORMAT(t.work_time,'%H:%i') AS workTime
       , w.wrktyp_name
       , t.remarks
       , DATE_FORMAT(t.tmsht_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS tmshtDate
       , wl.loctn_name
       , s.serv_name
       , t.status_code
       , t.conv_kms      AS convkms
       , t.conv_amount   AS convamount 
    FROM timesheets t
    JOIN accounts a
      ON a.accnt_code = t.accnt_code
    JOIN services s
      ON s.serv_code = t.serv_code 
    JOIN worktypes w
      ON w.wrktyp_code = t.wrktyp_code
    JOIN work_location wl
      ON wl.loctn_code = t.loctn_code 
    JOIN users
      ON u.usr_code = t.usr_code
   ORDER BY t.tmsht_date DESC
```

Ordering on the formatted date column is very odd. Much more likely you want results returned in "date" order, not in the string order with month and day before the year. (Do you really want to sort on the day value first, before the year?)

**FOLLOWUP**

If this same exact query complete quickly, with the entire resultset (of approx 720 rows) from a different client (same database, same user), then the issue is likely something *other* than this SQL statement.

We would not expect the execution of the SQL statement to cause PHP to "crash".

If you are storing the entire resultset (for example, using mysqli store_result), you need to have sufficient memory for that. But the thirteen expressions in the select list all look relatively short (formatted dates, names and codes), and we wouldn't expect "remarks" would be over a couple of KB.

For debugging this, as others have suggested, try adding a LIMIT clause on the query, e.g. `LIMIT 1` and observe the behavior.

Alternatively, use a dummy query for testing; use a query that is guaranteed to return specific values and a specific number of rows.

```
  SELECT 'morpheus'             AS accnt_name
       , 'trinity'              AS username
       , '01:23'                AS inTime
       , '04:56'                AS outTime
       , '00:45'                AS workTime
       , 'neo'                  AS wrktyp_name
       , 'yada yada yada'       AS remarks
       , '27-May-2015'          AS tmshtDate
       , 'zion'                 AS loctn_name
       , 'nebuchadnezzar'       AS serv_name
       , ''                     AS status_code
       , '123'                  AS convkms
       , '5678'                 AS convamount
```

I suspect that the query is *not* the root cause of the behavior you are observing. I suspect The problem is somewhere else in the code.

[**How to debug small programs** http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I completely agree that I should be using JOIN instead of the traditional where clause. And your point on sorting based on the formatted date is also a good one. I had not observed that.
However, the issue still remains even after I change the code to the one you have given. This is the first time I have faced such an issue.

And about the number of records in the result is not very high. It is just around 720 records.

Comment: I also believe that the query is not the cause of your problems. Do you run a local sql server or one on shared hosting? A few years ago i was one a sharede hosting service that had a terribly slow sql server due to overcapacity. A simple sql statement took way too long. Maybe this is the same with you.

Comment: I am running a local mysql instance. I have it on a shared hosting too, but I have the issue on my local instance itself.

Answer (score 1):

phpadmin automatically adds LIMIT to the query, that's why you got fast results.

1. Check how many rows are in table
2. Run your query with limit

Answer (score 1):

First of all: modify you query so that it looks like the one given by Spencer

Do you get an error message when your application 'crashes' or does it just stop?

You could try:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

in your php code. This sets the maximum execution time to unlimited. So if there are no errors, your script should execute to the end. So you can see if your query gets the desired results.

Also just as a test end your query with

```
 LIMIT 10
```

This should greatly speed up your query as it will only take the first ten results. 
You can later change this value to one better suited for your needs. Unless you absolutely need the complete result set, I suggest you always use LIMIT in your queries.

Comment: the `max_execution_time` setting was a little useful. The page ran for a longer time to give no errors, but it printed few echo's that I have given.